# How to tell which button was clicked?

Tags: java, selenium, button

I have a table with some entries (names). At each name I have the button "edit". My problem is, that all edit buttons have the same id.

Do you know how I can click the edit button for the 10. person in the table for example?

Answer (score 3):

We had a related problem using Selenium, the difference being that we don't know the value of the id attribute for Ajax enabled components. That is because we use Wicket, and it generates dynamic Ids in this situation.

What I did was to get Wicket to add a name attribute, and have Selenium select on this attribute instead of id.

Comment: The guy asking teh question should use names anyway over ids. And his main problem is not Selenium, but lack of basic XML knowledge and HTML, otherwise he would understand the XPath advices he got ...

Comment: Command : click; Target : css=a:contains("edit"); it cliks the first edit butoon from the list. Please tell my woh i can tell selenium to click the button from the person "ABC" of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selectors and use the nth-child attribute. For example on the stackoverflow main page you can select the second question with the following CSS selector:

```
.container .question-summary:nth-child(2)
```

You can also use XPath. The XPath for the same element would be:

```
//div[@class='question-summary']/div[2]
```

Comment: yeah, now I have it..using XPATH i can find any botton in my table (tr[10]/td[4]). How can I do this if I wanna search the name "ABC" and then automatically click the edit button for the person "ABC".

Comment: //div[contains(text(), "ABC")] or for CSS div:contains("ABC")

Comment: Command  : click; Target : //tr[3]/td[9]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/a;

Comment: with tihs target I can click the edit button for the person [3] in my table. How cand i search for a person o wanna edit. //div[contains(text(), "ABC")] at the target doesnt work . Sorry for asking again

Comment: Command : click; Target : css=a:contains("edit"); it cliks the first edit butoon from the list. Please tell my woh i can tell selenium to click the button from the person "ABC" of the list

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, if you have the same ID for every button this is wrong according to the HTML specification. Each ID should be unique to a page. You should probably remove the ID if you can't make it unique.

What you need sounds like it could be accomplished by using XPATH.

For example, you could use something like:

`//table[@class='myTableClass']/tr[10]/td[4]/input`

If you are searching for a particular value you can use "contains":

`//table[@class='myTableClass']//td[contains(., 'ABC')]../td[5]`

What that does is search for a table cell with the value `ABC`, then select the parent of that cell (the row), then select the 5th cell of that row. There's a lot you can do with Xpath.

For more info on Xpath see e.g. the [Xpath tutorial here](http://www.theautomatedtester.co.uk/tutorials/selenium/selenium_xpath.htm).

Comment: Your note on IDs is correct. Just to add however that sometimes you can't select by ID. For example, with Sencha Touch/ExtJS the IDs change dynamically.

Comment: yeah, now I have it..using XPATH i can find any botton in my table (tr[10]/td[4]). How can I do this if I wanna search the name "ABC" and then automatically click the edit button for the person "ABC".

Comment: Command : click; Target : css=a:contains("edit"); it cliks the first edit butoon from the list. Please tell my woh i can tell selenium to click the button from the person "ABC" of the list